# At the end of the Shaman Warrior manhwa, do Yaki and Horrakan die?

Tags: shaman-warrior

In the manhwa Shaman Warrior, does Yaki die in the end? They kinda abruptly cut the fight scene and ended with Yatilla yelling for Yaki years later. But before they cut out her fight, she was kicking butt in full shaman mode.

Also did Horrakan die? He was still alive when he and Nejo fell. Nejo came back alive... what happened with Horrakan? Ending seemed a little abrupt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shaman Warrior was abruptly canceled at that point in the story. The story was never finished and as a result, we are left at that eternal cliff hanger without knowing what happens of Yaki and others.

Even though the series had a great story and terrific art, this is the nature of the manhwa business. I have seen more abrupt ends to Manhwa than Manga or Comics.

The author and artist of Shaman Warrior, Park Joong Gi has moved on to another project called: The Arms Peddler, as the main artist. Which is ongoing and published by Square Enix. So if you would like to enjoy his work still, perhaps you should check it out. I personally like it.

Hope this helped and you'll continue to enjoy Manhwa.